# How to give width in percentage in react-bootstrap grid

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-hooks

How to give grid column width in percentage in react-bootstrap.

Comment: i want to give width in percentage in react-bootstrap grid column instead <col lg={2}></col>
here i use lg={} this for define breakpoint and give how many column use for make one column in that row, but i want give width in percentage, means make dynamic column width.

Answer (score -2):

Rather than using width in percentage its better to use pre defined classes in react-grid for more responsive grids.
You can visit the following link and choose the grid of your choice:
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/

Comment: So not helpful to just put a link (that is no longer working)